# What is the URL format for a tar filesystem in PyFilesystem?

Tags: python, pyfilesystem

Is there a URL format for the [TarFilesystem](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/tarfs.html) in PyFilesystem? I see other examples [here](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/openers.html), but not for [TarFilesystem](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/tarfs.html).

Comment: And what about the `tarfile` module ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html

Comment: In this case everything is PyFilesystem, it's a thin wrapper over things like `tarfile` and provides a consistent interface across many forms of file access (tar, os, s3, memory fs, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer through trial and error:

```
fs.open_fs('tar://~/tmp/testtar.tar.gz')
```

The resource part of the URL (`~/tmp/testtar.tar.gz`) can be an OS path including file expansion.